# Работа с модальными окнами (аналог)

Tags: jquery, html, блок

Прошу помощи у знающих jQuery, помощи.

На сайте будут ссылки при клике на которых открывается блок, что-то похожее на модальные окна.

Для этого делаю такие ссылки:

```
<a href="" id="win_a">Ссылка 1</a> 
<a href="" id="win_b">Ссылка 2</a> 
<a href="" id="win_c">Ссылка 3</a>
```

Блоки:

```
<div id="win_a_div">Содержимое 1</div>
<div id="win_b_div">Содержимое 2</div>
<div id="win_c_div">Содержимое 3</div>
```

jQuery код:

```
//block 1
$("#win_a").click(function () {
    if ($("#win_a_div").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#win_a_div").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#win_a_div").slideUp();
    }
});  
//block 2
$("#win_b").click(function () {
    if ($("#win_b_div").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#win_b_div").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#win_b_div").slideUp();
    }
});  
//block 3
$("#win_c").click(function () {
    if ($("#win_c_div").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#win_c_div").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#win_c_div").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Как видите код повторяется, как можно сделать, чтобы один код выполнял эти действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3KZgu/ надеюсь так

Comment: Благодарю за внимание. Почти так. Только нужно, чтобы каждый блок появлялся по очереди, т.е. нажимаем на ссылку 1 - открывается 1 блок, нажимаем на ссылку 2 - скрывается блок 1 и появляется блок 2

Comment: @zan1988, решил задачу совсем по-другому. Спасибо, за внимание.